# How to get all the topics and perc contribution and keywords for each document?

Tags: python, nlp, lda

I have read many articles that provide codes on obtaining dominant topic, perc contribution and keywords for each document, like the one coded below. However, I would like to obtain all topics, not just the dominant ones and their perc contribution, keywords. Would anyone know how to code that in Python?

```
def format_topics_sentences(ldamodel=lda_model, corpus=corpus, texts=data):
    # Init output
    sent_topics_df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Get main topic in each document
    for i, row in enumerate(ldamodel[corpus]):
        row = sorted(row, key=lambda x: (x[1]), reverse=True)
        # Get the Dominant topic, Perc Contribution and Keywords for each document
        for j, (topic_num, prop_topic) in enumerate(row):
            if j == 0:  # => dominant topic
                wp = ldamodel.show_topic(topic_num)
                topic_keywords = ", ".join([word for word, prop in wp])
                sent_topics_df = sent_topics_df.append(pd.Series([int(topic_num), round(prop_topic,4), topic_keywords]), ignore_index=True)
            else:
                break
    sent_topics_df.columns = ['Dominant_Topic', 'Perc_Contribution', 'Topic_Keywords']
```

Comment: you can use "ldamodel.components_" to get all topics (equal to number of topics used while creating LDA model)

Comment: @Arjit is this ldamodel.components_ applicable to gensim? I am using gensim.ldamodel

Comment: No, its not available in gensim. Its part of sklearn -> LatentDirichlet.